# How can I remove the shadow of the confirm button when deleting in a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How can I remove the shadow of the confirm button when deleting in a table view?

[image: Shadow of the confirm button]

Answer (score 0):

First, simply open the storyboard, click the button once to choose it and then set the shadow color to *Default* by clicking on the blue arrows:

[image: Xcode Sreenshot]

The, try the following programmatically in the `override func ViewDidLoad()`:

```
    self.buttonOutlet.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    self.buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    self.buttonOutlet.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    self.buttonOutlet.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
```

Replace `buttonOutlet` with the actual name of the button's outlet.

Let me know if that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve this ,We can custom to this button.
Handle on TableViewCell.

```
-(void)layoutIfNeeded {
    [super layoutIfNeeded];
    if ([self.subviews count] >= 4){
        for(UIView* subView in self.subviews){
            //DDLogDebug(@"JARED: subView %@",[subView class]);
            if([NSStringFromClass([subView class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellEditControl"]){
                for(UIView * subView2 in subView.subviews){

                    if ([subView2 isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]] && subView2.frame.origin.y == 20) {
                        subView2.layer.shadowRadius  = 11;
                        subView2.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
                        subView2.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
                        subView2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
                        subView2.layer.cornerRadius  = 11;
                        subView2.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
                        subView2.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
                        subView2.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"confirmDetele"].CGImage;


                    }
                    if ([subView2 isKindOfClass: [UIImageView class]] && subView2.frame.origin.y == 22) {

                        subView2.layer.contents = nil;
                        subView2.layer.shadowRadius  = 11;
                        subView2.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
                        subView2.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
                        subView2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1;
                        subView2.layer.cornerRadius  = 11;
                        subView2.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
                        subView2.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;


                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```